# Is there a way to browse the derived types of a base type using the Object Browser

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Obviously this would be scoped to the current solution, but I need to find all the types that inherit from a particular base type.  The Object Browser seems to only support backtracking through the inheritance tree from a given type.

Comment: On the "Browse" dropdown box of the Object Browser select an item other than "My Solution" or "All Components".

For example select ".NET Framework 4" or ".NET Framework 4.5"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, this is weird:

On [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exy1facf%28v=VS.100%29.aspx), it says:

> Show Derived Types
> Toggles display of derived types in the Objects pane. Available only for Visual C++ projects and the .NET Framework.

But the option 'Show Derived Types' doesnt appear for me in the Object Browser settings.

**Alternatively, if you have ReSharper its just:**

Press `alt` + `end` once you've clicked on the class in object browser.

Or right click on class > `Derived Symbols`.

Comment: vs2012 (maybe 2010 as well?) you can use "Class View" (different than Object Browser).  Browse to the type, r-click -> View Class Diagram.  Then, on the diagram, r-click on the type -> Show Derived Classes.

Comment: If you want to view derived classes of types from the >NET framework -- 
On the "Browse" dropdown box of the Object Browser select an item other than "My Solution" or "All Components".

For example select ".NET Framework 4" or ".NET Framework 4.5"

Answer (score -1):

With cursor on the type, right click - Inspect - Hierarchy

Comment: VS 2012 Premium: I do not see the "Inspect" menu option in the code editor or in the Object Browser.  Where do you see "Inspect"?